# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode' with lxml-python

Tags: python, string, lxml, encode, nonetype

I'm getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'` error when parsing out some XML patent inventor data. I'm trying to pull the first inventor plus their address infomation into a string as such below:

```
inventor1 = first(doc.xpath('//applicants/applicant/addressbook/last-name/text()'))
inventor2 = first(doc.xpath('//applicants/applicant/addressbook/first-name/text()'))
inventor3 = first(doc.xpath('//applicants/applicant/addressbook/address/city/text()'))
inventor4 = first(doc.xpath('//applicants/applicant/addressbook/address/state/text()'))
inventor5 = first(doc.xpath('//applicants/applicant/addressbook/address/country/text()'))
inventor = str(inventor2.encode("UTF-8")) + " " + str(inventor1.encode("UTF-8"))
inventors2 = str(inventor3.encode("UTF-8")) + ", " + str(inventor4) + ", " + str(inventor5)
inventors = str(inventor) + ", " + str(inventors2)

print "DocID: {0}\nGrantDate: {1}\nApplicationDate: {2}\nNumber of Claims: {3}\nExaminers: {4}\nAssignee: {5}\nInventor: {6}\n".format(docID,grantdate,applicationdate,claimsNum,examiners.encode("UTF-8"),assignees,inventors)
```

but there is problem as there is a `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character` for multiple parts in this long xml. I need to have the `.encodes` within my python so I don't create an error but by doing so I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\FINAL BART INFO ONE.py", line 87, in <module> inventor = str(inventor2.encode("UTF-8")) + " " + str(inventor1.encode("UTF-8"))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Is there anyway to either ignore the "None" values that are returned when nothing is there? Must I `def` or use a different type of `.encode` for my `print`?

By the way i'm creating a database from an input file is actually multiple XML files appending to one file. (Data file Sourced from [Google Patents](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/patents/grant_full_text/2010/ipg100105.zip)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always just do quick and dirty `str(inventor1.encode("UTF-8") if inventor1 else inventor1)`

Comment: I errored on on the next line being the `inventors2 = str(inventor3.encode("UTF-8")) + ", " + str(inventor4)`. Could I put your suggestion in as such for `str(inventor4 if inventor4 else inventor4)` ? Would this work?

Comment: Well, there it would have no point, as you'd be saying a if a else a and always get a.  There's only a point to x if y else z if x and z are different.  The problem in the next line isn't inventor4 anyway, it is that same encode call on inventor2, I would bet.  And for that you can use the x if y else z thing again.  The bigger question here though is why you aren't just doing this all in some sort of loop.

Comment: Hey your right- I got it to work. I just put them on the .encodes like you said for the `inventors2`. The reason I'm doing it this way is A) my boss wants me to produce the data this way so he can understand and B) I'm also limited in my knowledge of python and this method, while crude, allows me to gather everything I need when I'm parsing. Thanks for the helpful answer +1